# Automatically resizing Qt layout while dynamically adding labels?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm adding multiple labels containing pictures (`QPixmap`) into a certain layout, via a loop.
W
hen the labels are being added, their size is being reduced in order to stay inside the layout's borders.

Is there a way to add multiple labels into a layout, and the layout automatically having a scroller bar / automatically expanding (something similar to text being added to a small `QTextEdit` box)?

I tried setting the `ui->myLayout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinimumSize)` but it displays only part of the output and the rest is cut from displaying.

Comment: The containing widget has a resize method. Use it when you add your things to it, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: if you use layouts, `resize()` or `setGeometry()` will not work (or not as intended). You can give each `QLabel` in your loop a minimum/maximum size (`lbl->setMinimumSize(QSize()) / lbl->setMaximumSize(QSize))`) or a fixed size (`lbl->setFixedSize(QSize ())`). So that your window doesn't get bigger unexpectedly, you can also use `QScrollArea`, the `contentWidget` should also have a layout so that you can scroll.